# Latent partitioning variable governing unobservable dependent variables -- how to estimate?

Tags: estimation, modeling, latent-variable

I've got a situation where I'm willing to assume that 
$$
Q_t = Pe^{-k^f t} + (1-P)e^{-k^s t}
$$
This is a double-exponential decay model; there is a fast pool and a slow pool.  I don't know $P$, $k^f$ or $k^s$, but I observe $Q_t$ ($\in \{0,1\}$) and a bunch of covariates $D$ (dummies, these are confounders) and $X$, which is continuous, and of-interest.  Complicating matters slightly, observations are grouped -- this is meta-analytical data.

I'm willing to assume that $P$ is a function of random effects and $X$, and orthogonal to $D$.  Given $P$, $k^f$ and $k^s$ are orthogonal to $X$.  So in essence, what I've got is:

$$
g(E(P)) = \alpha^p + \mu_i^p+f(X) + \epsilon^p\\
g(E(k^f)) = \alpha^f + \mu_i^f +D'\beta^f + \epsilon^f\\
g(E(k^s)) = \alpha^s + \mu_i^s +D'\beta^s + \epsilon^s\\
$$

$P$ is in 0,1, and the rates $k$ are non-negative.

I want to be able to estimate $Q_t$ as a function of $X$ and $D$.

Intuitively, this seems like it should be estimable, but I can't quite figure out how to do it.  The other salient piece of information is that I've got variation in $t$, which maybe I could use to get a nonparametric estimate of $Q_t$ as a function of $t$, along with residuals, which maybe I could use as starting values (somehow?).

Anybody have any ideas for how to solve this?  Or, is there a particular method that does this that I could pull off of a shelf?